# Cannot install QubesOS: It says “No local disks” when I try to select destination

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, qubes-os

I tried to install QubesOS (Linux) on my laptop but when I get to the “Installation destination” part, in the device selection I have nothing to select and it says “No local disks.”

I don’t understand where is the problem and why the OS is not seeing my SSD. I tried to eject the USB to see if it was just a random error but I still get “No local disks.”

Am I doing something wrong? Why the OS is not seeing my SSD to install on it?

The laptop is a [ASUS X509FJ-EJ014](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-Laptop-15-X509FJ/specifications/) and the specs are:

- **CPU**: Intel Core i5 8265U
- **RAM**: 8GB DDR4 Ram
- **SSD**: 512 GB
- **GPU**: NVIDIA GeForce MX230 GDDR5

Answer (score 0):

#### It doesn’t seem like QubesOS supports the ASUS X509FJ line of machines.

Checking the [official hardware compatibility list for QubesOS](https://www.qubes-os.org/hcl/), I see a lot of ASUS models listed but I don’t see an entry for the X509FJ.